# Java - Regular Expressions Split on character after and before certain words

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble figuring out how to grab a certain part of a string using regular expressions in JAVA. Here's my input string:

```
application.APPLICATION NAME.123456789.status
```

I need to grab the portion of the string called `"APPLICATION NAME"`. I can't simply split on the period character becuase `APPLICATION NAME` may itself include a period. The first word, `"application`", will always remain the same and the characters after `"APPLICATION NAME"` will always be numbers.

I've been able to split on period and grab the 1st index but as I mentioned, `APPLICATION NAME` may itself include periods so this is no good. I've also been able to grab the first and second to last index of a period but that seems ineffecient and would like to future-proof by using REGEX.

I've googled around for hours and haven't been able to find much guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Which regexes did you use? How `status` can be written? There can be something after `status`?

Comment: The last property (in this case status) is dynamic but will always be one word and preceded by a period (i.e. ".status", ".expiration", ".whatever"). I've tried this so far:  `String appName = key.split("\\.")[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^application\.(.*)\.\d` with [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), or `application\.(.*)\.\d.*` with [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--).

Sample code using `find()`:

```
private static void test(String input) {
    String regex = "^application\\.(.*)\\.\\d";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    if (m.find())
        System.out.println(input + ": Found \"" + m.group(1) + "\"");
    else
        System.out.println(input + ": **NOT FOUND**");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("application.APPLICATION NAME.123456789.status");
    test("application.Other.App.Name.123456789.status");
    test("application.App 55 name.123456789.status");
    test("application.App.55.name.123456789.status");
    test("bad input");
}
```

*Output*

```
application.APPLICATION NAME.123456789.status: Found "APPLICATION NAME"
application.Other.App.Name.123456789.status: Found "Other.App.Name"
application.App 55 name.123456789.status: Found "App 55 name"
application.App.55.name.123456789.status: Found "App.55.name"
bad input: **NOT FOUND**
```

The above will work as long as "status" doesn't start with a digit.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, this works beautifully. Out of curiosity, it seems like I'm obligated to use m.find() before m.group(1) seems to work, otherwise it throws an exception. Seems a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

With `split()`, you could save `key.split("\\.")` in a `String[] s` and, in a second time, join from `s[1]` to `s[s.length-3]`.

With regexes you can do:

```
String appName = key.replaceAll("application\\.(.*)\\.\\d+\\.\\w+")", "$1");
```

Comment: You forgot to double the ``\``, and you don't need `^` and `$`.

Comment: you could also change `application` for `.*?` (less is more)

Comment: @Bohemian But question explicitly says *"The first word, "application", will always remain the same"*, so this is good too. You can argue *(and I do)* that it is better, since it will do nothing on "bad" input.

Comment: If input is "bad", using "application" will return the entire input as the app name (bad) and using `.*?` will return undetermined (also bad). Better to use an optional match so return is always blank on bad input (like my edited answer)

Comment: You can do the same speech (_If input is "bad"_) about the numbers or the final word. IMHO is better to do like this, then eventually he can verify if `key.equals(appName)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why split? Just:

```
String appName = input.replaceAll(".*?\\.(.*)\\.\\d+\\..*", "$1");
```

This also correctly handles a dot then digits within the application name, but only works correctly if you know the input is in the expected format.

To handle "bad" input by returning blank if the pattern is not matched, be more strict and use an optional that will always match (replace) the entire input:

```
String appName = input.replaceAll("^application\\.(.*)\\.\\d+\\.\\w+$|.*", "$1");
```

Comment: It doesn't *"correctly handles a dot then digits within the application name"* unless you remove the `?`, i.e. `(.*)`. For input `application.App.55.name.123456789.status` you get `App.55.name` without the `?` and just `App` with the `?`.